# Execute commands as different user via sudo over SSH in a justfile

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, heredoc, just

I have this justfile:

```
remote:
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    read -p 'Password:' -s password
    ssh -tt somewhere 'bash -l -s' << 'ENDSSH'
    whoami
    echo "$password" | sudo su someone 'bash -l -s' << 'ENDSUDO'
    whoami
    ENDSUDO
    ENDSSH
```

It should:

- Ask me for a password
- SSH into somewhere
- sudo to change the user
- execute some scripts

What it does:

It asks for a password a second time.
It stucks on input (no error message).

How to solve this problem?

### Update

As suggested by @xhienne, this does almost work, but it says, I use the wrong password:

```
remote:
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    read -p 'Password:' -s password
    ssh -tt somewhere 'bash -l -s' << 'ENDSSH'
    sudo -S -i -u someone << ENDSUDO
    $password
    whoami
    ENDSUDO
    exit
    ENDSSH
```

But this does work:

```
remote:
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    read -p 'Password:' -s password
    ssh -tt somewhere 'bash -l -s' << 'ENDSSH'
    sudo -S -i -u someone << ENDSUDO
    clear-text-password
    whoami
    ENDSUDO
    exit
    ENDSSH
```

### Update 2

The answer of @xhienne does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
echo "$password" | sudo su someone 'bash -l -s' << 'ENDSUDO'
    whoami
ENDSUDO
```

You are redirecting stdin twice:

- once with `|`
- a second time with `<<`

Try this:

```
sudo -S -i -u someone << ENDSUDO
$password
whoami
ENDSUDO
```

`sudo -S` will read the password from stdin. `sudo -i` is a substitute for the ugly `sudo su bash -l` (but it needs that `sudo` be properly configured for `-u someone`)

Note that I removed the quotes around ENDSUDO. Beware of inadvertent substitutions. If you must keep ENDSUDO quoted, then you can try this instead:

```
{
    echo "$password"
    cat << 'ENDSUDO'
whoami
ENDSUDO
} | sudo -S -i -u someone
```

Comment: I think you are missing `-u someone` in your `sudo` commands.

Comment: Thanks @Shane, I completely missed that "someone". I think this explains why they are using "sudo su"

Comment: I need to take back my solved-mark, sorry. It works well, if I write the password in clear text but not if I write the password in a variable.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect the problem.

Comment: @mogoh When used correctly, there is no difference between a text in a variable and a plain text. You probably missed my note about removing the quotes around ENDSUDO? The same applies to ENDSSH of course. PS: what you are doing --reusing the same stdin to send the password as well as commands and nesting two here-documents-- is really not what I would do as this is error-prone and booby-trapped, but this is what you chose to do. I tried to respect your choice in my answer, and what I propose works (tested).

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I missed to remove quotes around ENDSSH. I thought, it would be a quick and simple solution, but it turned out to be more complex that I initially hoped for. Bash turns out to have a lot of foot-traps.

Comment: @mogoh This mishap is partly my fault as I chose to focus on your actual error (double stdin redirection) and didn't reuse your complete code, with the two nested heredocs. I assumed you had a good understanding of shell syntax, especially the difference between ENDSSH being quoted or not. The whole construct is not very solid: `echo "$pass"` has side effects if `$pass` begins with a dash (use printf), if one of your line begins with ssh's escape character (see man) you might get surprising results (avoid `ssh -t`), passing a pass through stdin to sudo, especially along with other commands...

Comment: ... is very risky: if for any reason `sudo` doesn't read the password, you may get `"MyPreci0u$": command not found` in your logs/on your screen (solution: don't sudo, instead connect to the root account with ssh; alt solution: create a special account and configure it correctly so that it can use that special command with sudo without password). All in all, instead of pushing your commands with heredocs, the best is probably to create a script on the remote machine and just run it with ssh (traps removed, easier debugging and you then can run your script manually when connected remotely).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following will work, if you only want to run `whoami` instead of several commands:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -s -p 'Password: ' password
ssh somewhere whoami
echo "$password" | ssh somewhere sudo -S -u someone whoami
```

The `-S` tells `sudo` to read the password from stdin.

If you want to run several commands with a here-document, see [@xhienne's  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356288/8593689).

Comment: Your answer is correct. I may be wrong but, judging by the original command and its two nested here-documents, I assume that the poster has a good grasp of shell syntax and ssh usage, and that they really want their here-documents.